# Version code is changed automatically in build

Tags: android

When I generate play store apk then version code is changed automatically. Here is how I define version in flavouring. How can I fix it? Any help is highly appriciated.

```
    core {
        dimension DIMENSION_APP_TYPE
        applicationId "com.xyz"
        versionCode 17
        versionName "1.1.6"
    }
```

26323252

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you are using APK split feature, then for every APK it will have different version code
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits

Comment: @akashzincle Thank you, but I'm not using APK split feature